# Can we use ui:include in JSF to display a component?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am new to JSF and I am trying to display a JSF2 component with ui:include

```
<ui:include src="myComponent.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="attr" value="aValue"/>
</ui:include>
```

The component is successfully displayed but the param is **not** passed to the JSF2 component. the attribute attr is defined in the interface of the component.

It works if I use my component this way:

```
<ez:myComponent attr="aValue"/>
```

The point in using ui:include is to use something like that:

```
<ui:include src="#{componentName}"/>
```

Am I doing something that is not supported or is there another way to display my component and have the parameters filled?

I am using GlassFish v3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Are you trying to use <ui:include src="#{componentName}"/> ? If so what is the rest of your code and how are you expecting to see the param set?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I want to include dynamically some JSF2 components and I was wondering if it was possible. The name of the component is provided by a bean of my own.
During my tests if I declare my component as <ez:myComponent attr="aValue">, the component is displayed correctly. But I can't display a component dynamically with that semantic.
So I tried with ui:include and the component is displayed but the value of the attribute "attr" is not passed to the component.
For the component, let's say it just does <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.attr}"/>.

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding of ui:param  you should be able to acess the value of the ui:param
in myComponent.xhtml by using #{attr} which by using param name
check this out https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-param

Comment: Well I tried to put in ui:param a name of cc.attrs.attr so that it would correspond to what my component uses. It did not work. I guess that what I'm trying to achieve is just not possible now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in Inv3r53's answer: Periods have a special meaning in expression language to evaluate chains of expressions. If you want your page to be both standalone and used as a component then use a c:set ([JSF 2 doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html)) outside of your composition tags to set `cc.attrs.attr` to `attr`. The set will be used if standalone, but left out when included (only the stuff between the composition tags is included).